# Real ADC value BLE113

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, adc

I would like to ask you for advice regarding the real value calculation from the ADC. I use `call hardware_adc_read(6,1,2)` set up. The BLE113 is supplied by 3V.

Voltage = ADC value * 3V / 2048 is close to the real value. However, 2048 number does not make sense for me. I thought, there should be 512/4096 because of the setup of `hardware_adc_read(6,1,2)` where 1 should be 2^9 = 512 or because of the ADC resolution which should be 2^12 = 4096.

I am a little bit confused. If you can help me with this computation, I would be grateful.

Thank you,

Daniel